# How to add a path to PATH variable in linux alpine for the entire machine?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, path, alpine-linux

I know I can `export PATH="$PATH:my_path"` to add to `PATH` variable in current session.

I also know that I can add this line to `~/.bash_profile` to make it persist across sessions for my user:

`echo 'PATH="$PATH:my_path"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

I also know that in linux `ubuntu` I can add that line to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and it's avaiable always for all users.

However, my linux inside the container is `alpine` and I don't know where to add that file. I couldn't find it in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine Linux uses by default ash as shell, it is quite similar to bash. The settings for everyone would be in the file /etc/profile

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35357011/2955337

if I had to find this myself I would run a find to see where PATH was set, I would grep through the etc directory.

```
grep "PATH=" /etc/*
```

Comment: Yeah, it's in the `/etc/profile`. But it seems that docker interactive shell `sh` does not honor that file. Because I still can't call my command, though its path is already been added to `/etc/profile` **PATH**.

Comment: than set the path in the Dockerfile as ENV PATH="/opt/bin". You can extend an existing Dockerfile by specifing it as a FROM